# Google indexing and ranking a custom domain served by Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google, google-search-console

I have a website served on the following URL: `http://www.plugimmo.com` which is a custom domain served by Google App Engine on the following URL: plugimmo.appspot.com.

**Optimizing Google Indexing and Rankings**

For some time I have tried to optimize the Google indexing and ranking with no success. The problem is that searching on Google the keywords in the title of my home page does not retrieve my website at all even not in the 1,000 first results.

When checking the cached version of Google (cache: www.plugimmo.com), it says that the cached version is the one of 20-Aug-12 of "plugimmo.appspot.com". It looks there are several issues :

1. List The cached version is really old. I have made a lot of changes since the 20-Aug-12 and I saw the [GoogleBOT] crawling my site several times.
2. The cached version is for plugimmo.appspot.com
3. When looking at the Google Webmaster tools, I see that the number of pages indexed for www.plugimmo.com is 0, but that can't be the case given the number of changes I made since then.

**My Questions Would Therefore Be The Following**

- Why is the version of the cache so old although I saw the [GoogleBOT]
  crawling the site many times since 20-Aug-12?
- Is there a problem with indexing a custom domain served by Google App
  Engine?
- Why is the Google Webmaster tools showing 0 pages indexed although
  new pages have been crawled and that no errors have been reported
  in the indexing?

The Website is developed with Google Web Toolkit. guidelines have been followed regarding crawling Ajax sites. Bots are redirected to `http://www.plugimmo.com/HomeSnapshot.html`

Comment: If you corrected this problem please let us know how you fixed it and mark it with your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Google's cached version of your website does not necessarily reflect the 'freshness' of their index
- There are no problems associated with indexing a website hosted with Google App Engine
- Just because Google crawls a webpage does not mean that they will index it. Take a look at site:www.plugimmo.com for all of your indexed pages.

This might have to do with the age of your website. It is very difficult to get a new domain to rank well in Google.

Also after briefly reviewing your website, it looks like your entire navigation in done in JavaScript. This might be making it difficult for Google to reach these pages. I would check your logs and see if googlebot is able to follow your navigation. It might also be a good idea to create a [sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184&from=40318&rd=1) and to submit it to Google in [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

Answer (score 0):

This is how Google sees your website: [Spiderview](http://rapid.searchmetrics.com/en/seo-tools/site-analysis/spiderview,26.html)

As you see, there is no content on your main page, only 97 characters! Google doesn't like that.

You might be able to make yourself popular to Google by having lots of back links from popular and high ranked pages...

I don't know how to tell this in pro-language because I'm just a newbie myself! you should put some content in your main page and just hide it from normal users, but not from the Google... I heard this somewhere... you can even do similar thing for things inside an iframe which can't be seen by Google...